# Pause a running thread in MFC

Tags: mfc

I have created a thread using `AfxBeginThread()` in Visual Studio 2010 (vc++) professional edition.
Is there exist any medium by which I can pause (running )same thread handle?
I tried using `SuspendThread()`, but after this I have no control of the thread , so I can't resume the same thread using `ResumeThread()` function.
Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: The `AfxBeginThread` function returns a pointer to a `CWinThread` object. As long as you 'save' this pointer somewhere accessible to your controller's code, you can call its `SuspendThread()` and `ResumeThread()` member functions as and when you need to. Why are you trying to use thread "handles?"

Comment: Suspending threads is a sure recipe for disaster. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, suspending a thread is not a solution. What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to create functions called start ,stop or pause.So my thread will behave accordingly. I am able to start and stop the thread. But facing problem in pause operation.I tried SuspendThread(), but after this I don't have control of my application and cant use ResumeThread() for my application further. So if  Paused operation called, it will paused the thread.

Comment: You cannot safely suspend a thread. A thread can be put to sleep without suspending it. But you haven't explained, what *specific* problem you are trying to solve, so there's little we can do to help.

Comment: I am trying to create replica of music library where same thread is used to play the music,pause or stop the music. So how can I implement the same?

Comment: By playing, pausing, and stopping music playback. None of that requires suspending a thread. In fact, none of that even requires multithreading on your part.

Comment: suppose I started a thread using AfxBeginThread and want to use the same thread for performing stop,play or pause operation.

Comment: Forget everything about threads and simply tell us what your program is supposed to do. _"I am trying to create replica of music library..."_ is not enough information. Also read [this](http://xyproblem.info/), especially the very first sentence.

Comment: You don't need a dedicated thread in your application to render audio. [How to Play Media Files with Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/how-to-play-unprotected-media-files) explains, how to do it properly.